# (From dask distributed) ImportError: cannot import name 'scheduler'

Tags: python-3.x, dask-distributed

I'm trying to set up a distributed computing with scheduler, a worker and a client 
when I try to import scheduler with the below command:

```
from dask.distributed import Scheduler
```

it throws Import Error:

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-dfd9b2c6541f> in <module>
----> 1 from dask.distributed import Scheduler

ImportError: cannot import name 'Scheduler'
```

Installed dask distributed with the following command:

```
sudo python -m pip install dask distributed --upgrade
```

What could be done?

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it simply a case problem ?

Looking at [dask's repo](https://github.com/dask/distributed/blob/f7a0d7a8e5a729e84f695b8efb593e590c0ec2f4/distributed/deploy/tests/test_spec_cluster.py#L6), it seems you should import it this way:

```py
from dask.distributed import Scheduler
```

Note the uppercase S.

Comment: Nope I did the same way you have given, sorry for misspelling it in the question

Comment: Must be an environment problem then, because it works when imported this way.

I did a  `python -m pip install dask distributed` in a Python 3.7 virtualenv, and an interpreter in the same env could do the import successfully.

Are you sure that you're using the same Python environment as the one you installed the libraries in ?

Comment: Thanks for giving hint!!!!  Replacing python with python3 in the command solved my problem..  python3 -m pip install dask distributed